# How to create unique type for lambdas?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I want to create a helper function for a for-cycle that only runs from the second iterations because I have a lots of code with the following pattern:

```
firstItem = true;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  firstItem ? firstItem = false : std::cout << ",\n";
  std::cout << i;
}
```

I started to think a helper function for this, and I came up with this solution:

```
template <typename T>
void fromSecondIter(T fn)
{
  static bool firstItem = true; // because of this it works with unique types only
  if (firstItem)
    firstItem = false;
  else
    fn();
}
```

My problem is that this solution is working correctly when T is a unique type. So passing a lambda is ok, but passing a function will silently cause error. Then I wraped that fn parameter to a lambda, but surprisingly it does not help;

Here is a full example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void fromSecondIter(T fn)
{
  static bool firstItem = true;
  if (firstItem)
    firstItem = false;
  else
    fn();
}

template <typename T>
void iterTest(T fn)
{
  std::cout << "Numbers: ";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    fromSecondIter([&fn](){ fn(); }); // bad, why lambda is not unique here???
    std::cout << i;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void foo()
{
  std::cout << ", ";
}

void test()
{
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // ok, lambda is unique
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // ok, lambda is unique
  iterTest(foo); // ok
  iterTest(foo); // bad
}

int main()
{
  test();

  return 0;
}
```

this prints:

```
Numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Numbers: , 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Each lambda literal has got unique type, not each instance of lambda object.

Comment: «this solution is working correctly» ― for some definition of "correctly". Have you tried a nested loop?

Comment: @jrok: I think this is the real answer

Comment: @n.m.: You are right, it is not reentrant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda expressions create unique types, but that doesn't mean that every time execution passes over one in the code that a new unique type is created:

```
int main() {
  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    [] { std::cout << "Hello, World\n"; }();
  }
}
```

The above for loop creates three objects all of the same type.

In your code you have a template function, `iterTest`, that contains a lambda expression. This means that for each instantiation of `iterTest` the lambda expression will have a unique type. However if you run the same instantiation of `iterTest` the lambda expression have the same type each time. That's what's going on here.

As an example here's one workaround, with minimal changes for your example code:

```
template <typename T>
void iterTest(T fn)
{
  std::cout << "Numbers: ";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    fromSecondIter(fn);
    std::cout << i;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void test()
{
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // ok, lambda is unique
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // ok, lambda is unique
  iterTest([]{foo();}); // ok
  iterTest([]{foo();}); // also ok
}
```

---

Your current implementation of `fromSecondIter` will create a static variable that lasts from its creation until the end of the program, and memory will be reserved for it from the beginning of the program. It's not a huge cost, but there's a better way; Create an object that has a bool member variable instead, along with a member function (e.g., `operator()`) with the necessary logic.

```
#include <iostream>

struct skipper {
  bool first = true;

  template<typename Fn>
  void operator() (Fn &&fn) {
    if (first)
      first = false;
    else
      fn();
  }
};

int main()
{
  skipper skip_first;
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    skip_first([]{ std::cout << ", "; });
    std::cout << i;      
  }
}
```

It means using it takes two lines instead of one, but now you have control over the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating template-functions for each lambda makes a new function definition. Because lambda function types are different (even if they have same declaration).

So every definition has its own `static firstItem`.

But for `foo` there is just one definition, then the `static` will be changed after first call for `foo`:

```
iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // iterTest, fromSecondIter for this lambda
iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; }); // iterTest, fromSecondIter for this lambda
iterTest(foo);                        // iterTest, fromSecondIter for this foo
iterTest(foo);                        // uses above functions
```

A naive example to demonstrate the issue is:

```
template <int i>
struct foo
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
};


void test()
{
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; });
  iterTest([](){ std::cout << ", "; });
  iterTest(foo<1>());
  iterTest(foo<2>());
}
```

`foo<1>()` and `foo<2>()` are different types, so it will make two different `fromSecondIter` for them. Then `firstItem` is unchanged.

Comment: You are right, but I wrapped foo in a lambda in line "fromSecondIter([&fn](){ fn(); });"

Comment: You're passing same `foo` as `fn` to `fromSecondIter`. It doesn't matter `[&fn](){fn();};` is unique or not.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but the right answer for me is came from @jrok: "Each lambda literal has got unique type, not each instance of lambda object."